# heartbeat: Bad nodename in /etc/ha.d//haresources [node1]

Tags: high-availability, failover, heartbeat, heartbeat1

I'm trying to start heartbeat on Ubuntu 10.04 with `service heartbeat start`, but getting the following errors:

```
heartbeat[24829]: 2011/11/22_19:31:07 ERROR: Bad nodename in /etc/ha.d//haresources [node1]
heartbeat[24829]: 2011/11/22_19:31:07 ERROR: Configuration error, heartbeat not started.
```

On on server `uname -n` produces `loadb1`, on the second server `uname -n` produces `loadb2`. The two servers can ping each other okay with those names.

This is `/etc/ha.d/ha.cnf` on both servers:

```
debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
logfile /var/log/ha-log
logfacility     local0
keepalive 2
deadtime 10
udpport 694
bcast eth1
ucast eth0 my.external.ip
ucast eth0 my.external.ip
ucast eth1 10.0.0.5
ucast eth1 10.0.0.6
#udp     eth0
node    loadb1
node    loadb2
auto_failback off
```

And this is `/etc/ha.d/haresources` on both servers:

```
node1 IPaddr::46.20.121.113 httpd smb dhcpd
```

Authkeys is also set up.

What am I doing wrong?

The part where I'm least clear is the ucast/bcast lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `loaddb1` into the haresources - not `node1`.

Comment: Yup, that's it. D'oh!